# how to link utf-8 textfile to android textView?

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, hyperlink, textview

i want to link my text file(.txt) to android text view. the text includes persian texts (utf-8) that the text view does not shows it correctly. i think because the unicode format but i have no idea to how change it to utf-8. notice that this project does not connect to web service. so very appreciated for your help.

code:

```
 TextView txtShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
    InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);

    try {
        String StrFile = InputStreamToString(iFile);
        txtShow.setText(StrFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private String InputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataInputStream dataIo = new DataInputStream(is);
    String strLine = null;
    try {
        while ((strLine = dataIo.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
        }
        dataIo.close();
        is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you put that file somewhere on the internet where we can grab it?

Comment: You could alsoo try to read the file in a byte buffer and append the buffer like stringBuilder.append( new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));

Comment: Did you try: dataIo.readUTF(); ?

Comment: i did this but "dataIo.readUTF()" does not work.